# Does double encryption occur when Outlook Anywhere automatically encrypts MAPI data?

Tags: exchange-2010, encryption, autodiscovery, bpos, microsoft-office-365

Does this checkbox mean that MAPI-based RPC data will be encrypted and then encapsulated over HTTPS, resulting in double encryption?

[image]

I'm asking this question [based on this understanding of terms.](https://serverfault.com/q/393625/51457)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MAPI encryption that is enabled by default is between your Exchange servers and Outlook, *within your LAN.* Outlook Anywhere uses https over the Internet. I would not use http over the Internet, but internally there might be some benefits (eg with older clients).